# Verificar se um aplicativo esta instalado no aparelho

Tags: android

Estou precisando de ajuda para verificar se um aplicativo esta instalado no aparelho do usuário.

Situação 1: Preciso realizar uma busca no celular do usuário e verificar se existe alguns aplicativos instalados. Caso encontre esses aplicativos instalados retornar através de uma método a lista de aplicativos.

Situação 2: Disponibilizar essa lista de aplicativos instalados para ser consumido por outro aplicativo.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Eis um bom começo: [How to check programmatically if an application is installed or not in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392183/how-to-check-programmatically-if-an-application-is-installed-or-not-in-android)

Comment: O que voce quer dizer com "consumido"? O que você já tentou implementar? Nos de mais informações para te ajudar a progredir no que você já tentou implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter uma lista com a informação referente a todas as aplicações instaladas use o método [getInstalledApplications()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29) do PackageManager:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> list = 
           packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

A lista retornada tem um objecto [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) por cada aplicação instalada.

Para filtrar e obter apenas aquelas que que são da *category* `"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"` use o seguinte método:

```
private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return applist;
}
```

<sub>[Fonte](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android)</sub>